# jQuery UI drop within droppable children

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag

I want to drag and drop an element inside a container. The container will have sub-containers where the draggable elements can be dropped as well. Although when i drag the element inside the sub-containers, the element is instead appended to the main container and not the sub-container.

Drag a red div inside the blue div, then drag a purple div inside the red container that you just appended to the blue div.

It instead appends to the main container and not the red one that you dropped it ontop of.

How can i have the purple div append to either the blue div, or the red div depending on which div your dropped it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nested droppables (**greedy** is very important here):

```
/* drop on page canvas */
$("#drop").droppable({
    accept: ".inside-drag, .drag",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var target = $(event.target);
        var dropped = $(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo(target);
        if (dropped.hasClass('drag')) {
            dropped.droppable({
                accept: ".inside-drag",
                greedy: true,
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    var target = $(event.target);
                    $(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo(target);
                },
            });
        }
    },
});
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IBoiD)

Comment: This works. Although i forgot to mention that each red div has 3 sections, and I want to actually drop it within the sections of the red div depending on the section dropped, and not the red div itself.

Comment: Can you give more details? What means "red div has 3 sections"? Do you want to capture the position where the purple div was dropped or sth else?

Comment: No. I simply want to append the div to the sections inside the dragged and dropped element(red div) Heres what i mean http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eoEdK I want to drop the element within the sections of the red div.